# Position RadioButton XAML on center bottom of content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to position the WPF radio button on the centered bottom of an image. Currently I have a stackpanel with the image then radio button on the bottom but I'd like it so clicking the image triggers the radio button.

When I tried to embed the image inside the radiobutton, it only shows up on the right of the button. How can I do this using a static resource?

This is what I have for putting the radio button on top but I don't know if adjusting the margins is a good way to do it.

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonBottom" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <RadioButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" Margin="35 0 0 0" >
                <TextBlock>
                <LineBreak />
                <InlineUIContainer>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="-50,0,0,0" 
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.Content}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate}"/>
                </InlineUIContainer>
                </TextBlock>

            </RadioButton>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how it is at the moment and a quick-n-dirty paint sketch of how you would like it to look?

Comment: Added a pic, did not have enough reputation to do so before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that was harder than I'd expect it to be.. The default `RadioButton` uses `BulletDecorator` internally, and you don't have much control of the bullet's placement.

Therefore, creating a new `ControlTemplate` (which you did) seems to be the best option. With a little help from this article: [How to configure the WPF RadioButton's circle bullet](http://www.rhyous.com/2011/04/20/how-to-configure-the-wpf-radiobuttons-circle-bullet-top-aligned-when-there-are-multiple-lines-of-text/), here is another suggestion:

*Note: You need to add a reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero` in your project.*

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton" >
            <Setter Property="Template" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <DockPanel Background="Transparent" >
                            <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:BulletChrome DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                   IsRound="true" Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                                                                   BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                                                   IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" 
                                                                   RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" />
                            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
                        </DockPanel>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" >
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>


    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <RadioButton>
            <Image Source="..." />
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton>
            <Image Source="..." />
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton>
            <Image Source="..." />
        </RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Comment: Excellent solution, works exactly as intended after adding the reference to the .dll. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using a stack panel:

XAML:

```
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,125,50">
            <Image Source="Resources/rdo1.BackgroundImage.jpg" Height="87" Width="97" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10"/>
            <RadioButton GroupName="Type" x:Name="rdo1" Checked="rdo1_CheckedChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="125,0,0,50" PreviewMouseDown="test1">
            <Image Source="Resources/rdo2.BackgroundImage.png" Height="87" Width="97" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10"/>
            <RadioButton GroupName="Type" x:Name="rdo2" Checked="rdo2_CheckedChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnOk" Height="23" Width="76" TabIndex="1" IsEnabled="False" Click="btnOk_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="84,0,82,10" Content="OK" />
    </Grid>
```

I am assuming you want to click the image and have it select the radio, I added the PreviewMouseDown and the following:

```
private void test1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    rdo2.IsChecked = true;
}
```

To me this is easier than importing a dll.